# Load webpage to generate cookies then go to another website

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where I'm using my website for my real estate business.  My broker has a website where when a user goes to my profile on their domain, it generates a cookie so when they click on property finder, it let's the page know I'm the referring agent.  If you go to the property finder without going to my profile, it just assigns a random agent.

What I'm trying to do is when someone clicks to search properties, it loads my profile from the broker in the background to generate that session cookie, but then take them to the property finder so they can search properties but that cookie makes sure they do it with me as the agent.

I tried this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$.get('http://my.profile.com').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
<script>
```

But what I end up getting is e.indexOf is not a function.  Since my website is on my own server.  I do have the option of just making a php file to use as a link to load the website then redirect, but I'm not sure if I can do that to generate those cookies I need to make sure the user get's me as their agent.  Any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not honorable. You should ask your broker for a solution, not implement a workaround that cheats the system and fools the user. Also, firing a cross domain request will never return you a response but the browser will complete it.

Comment: Not honourable?  I'm having them use their system but go directly to the page.  They have a setup for it, but the problem is that when you go in you have to go through the profile first, then click on the property search link.  They flat out told me to direct link to the property search and it'll automatically use me as the agent.  Problem is that it's not working, when I check why it's because that cookie doesn't get generated on the property search page, but on the profile page. There's nothing wrong with what I'm trying to do, their people just don't know how to do it. That's why I'm here.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with this. Some systems work this way. But you should probably go read the jQuery docs before you post here.

Comment: That's fine, I'll just do it server side rather than messing around with scripting languages.  Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this code block,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> <-- opens a tag that never closes
$.get('http://my.profile.com').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
<script><-- opens a tag that never closes
```

...there are issues with your script tags.

This might work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get('http://my.profile.com').done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting $ is undefined.

Comment: This is some really basic jQuery stuff. You're basically asking the SO community to write your code for you. I'm sorry, I don't feel right about helping you further.

Comment: That's fine, I'll just do it server side.  I was hoping to be able to just add it to the front end not not have to route it through another page, but I guess it'll be quicker for me to do it with something I'm familiar with rather than a scripting language.  Thanks though!